# How to show a personalized error/warning/info message in a popup window?

Tags: jsf, popup, message

Hi I want to show a popup message about errors or warnings in my app, for example if a user try to enter a registry that is already in the data base. I'm working with JSF and my app doesn't add a registry that is already in the data base but I need to show a message that informs the user about that.
Thanks.

Comment: Does it really need to be an annoying and 90s style popup which you have to click away? Why not just a message next to the field in the same page which blocks the form submit when present?

Comment: Ok, I give up with the popup because I tried to do with icefaces but all goes wrong, my page is shown like a mess I don't know why. I'm doing the way you suggest but how can I block the form submit, I mean: when I add a new registry of users (my createUser.jspx for example) the navigation rule is to go to my users.jspx (that shows all users) if the data is already in the DB, the app shows the message but in the users.jspx, and I want the message to show in the createUser.jspx. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specifically for icefaces (since I read in comments that the @Mel is working with icefaces.

**To open a popup in icefaces:**

```
<ace:dialog widgetWar="mydialog">
    <h:outputText value="This is a dialog" />
</ace:dialog>
```

Then call this popup in your xhtml code like this:
E.g. I am using a command link that when clicked opens the popup.

```
<h:commandLink onlick="mydialog.show()" action="#{myBean.doSomething()}" />
```

---

**To show messages in dialog:**

```
<h:form id="myform">
<ace:dialog id="mydialog" widgetWar="mydialog">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
        <ace:messages id="allMsgsAdd" initEffect="highlight" for="myform:mydialog" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:outputText value="This is a dialog" />
</ace:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Then you can use this code to push messages to the `ace:message` you just created.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(SEVERITY_INFO, "My Message", null));
```

Please note that SEVERITY_INFO is a FacesMessage defined constant. You will need to import it. Depending on whether you need to show warning or error to user, you can import these

```
import static javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR;
import static javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO;
```

Also note the first parameter of `addMessage()` method. You will notice that I am passing `null` as the first paramter. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29), and you will find that the first paramter is the client id, which basically means that which client do you want to send this message to.  If clientId is null, this FacesMessage is assumed to not be associated with any specific component instance. So all of the message dialogs in your page will receive this error/warning. If you wish to **ONLY** show the message on the dialog, you need to pass your dialog client id here like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myform:mydialog", new FacesMessage(SEVERITY_INFO, "My Message", null));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some existing open source JSF component library .Many of them already provide the pop-up UI . For example ,Richfaces  provides it  by  . You can refer to this official link to see how to use : http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html

Comment: thank you, I forgot to mention that I'm working with icefaces.

Comment: icefaces has the `<ice:panelPopup>` to provide the pop-up UI. Here is the official tutorial link :  http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/panelPopup-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Check my asnwer in another question, maybe it will be useful for you

[How do I get a richfaces modal window to display without an onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563799/how-do-i-get-a-richfaces-modal-window-to-display-without-an-onclick-event/4586274#4586274)

This will show your exception messages (or another message added by you in middle of the code) in a `<rich:modalPanel>`.

Comment: Thank you Renan, I try to do that but it doesn't show the popup message, but it says INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed. Why is that?

Comment: You remember to put the `showWhenRendered="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity != null}"` in your modalPanel?

Comment: yes, I tell you that the pop up appears without any message but just when i'm trying to go to another page, not in the page that should be.